# How can we pass a list of strings to a fine tuned bert model?

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, huggingface-tokenizers

I want  to pass a list of strings instead of a single string input to my fine tuned bert question classification model.
This is my code which accept a single string input.

```
questionclassification_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('/content/drive/MyDrive/questionclassification_model')
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-cased')

def prepare_data(input_text):
    token = tokenizer.encode_plus(
        input_text,
        max_length=256, 
        truncation=True, 
        padding='max_length', 
        add_special_tokens=True,
        return_tensors='tf'
    )
    return {
        'input_ids': tf.cast(token['input_ids'], tf.float64),
        'attention_mask': tf.cast(token['attention_mask'], tf.float64)
    }

def make_prediction(model, processed_data, classes=['Easy', 'Medium', 'Hard']):
    probs = model.predict(processed_data)[0]
    return classes[np.argmax(probs)],probs;
```

I don't want to use a for loop over the list as it takes more execution time.
when I tried to pass a list as input to the tokenizer it was returning same output for every input.

```
input_text = ["What is gandhi commonly considered to be?,Father of the nation in india","What is the long-term warming of the planets overall temperature called?, Global Warming"]
processed_data = prepare_data(input_text)
```

---

{'input_ids': <tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 256), dtype=float64, numpy=
array([[101., 100., 100., 102.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,
0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,
0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,
0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,
0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,
0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,
0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,
0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,
0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,
0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,
0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,
0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,
0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,
0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,
0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,
0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,
0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,
0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,
0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,
0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,
0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,
0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,
0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,
0.,   0.,   0.]])>, 'attention_mask': <tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 256), dtype=float64, numpy=
array([[1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])>}

---

and that is not the right tokens for the input text.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Different methods for one sentence vs batches

There are different methods for encoding one sentence versus encoding a batch of sentences
According to the documentation (https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.21.1/en/internal/tokenization_utils#transformers.PreTrainedTokenizerBase.encode_plus) the `encode_plus` method expects the first parameter to be "This can be a string, a list of strings (***tokenized string using the tokenize method***) or a list of integers (tokenized string ids using the convert_tokens_to_ids method)."
(emphasis mine) - so that if you're passing a list of strings to this particular method, they are interpreted as *a list of tokens*, not sentences, and obviously all those very long "tokens" like "What is gandhi commonly considered to be?,Father of the nation in india" do not match anything in the vocabulary so they get mapped to the out-of-vocabulary id.

If you want to encode a batch of sentences, then you need to pass your list of strings to the `batch_encode_plus` method (https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.21.1/en/internal/tokenization_utils#transformers.PreTrainedTokenizerBase.batch_encode_plus)

Comment: Thats really worked !!..Thankyou soo much..can you help me to change the make_prediction function according to the returned output from prepare_data?

Answer (score 0):

It is already supported by hugging face by default. both tokenizer and model accept a list. See here tokenizer's documentation: https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/tokenizer#transformers.PreTrainedTokenizer.__call__

```
samples = ["some text1", "some_text2"]
inputs = tokenizer(samples)
predictions = questionclassification_model(inputs)
```

Comment: But when I try to pass a list it was returning same output for all the inputs.

Comment: for the models from hugginface it is working. But, this is a fine-tuned model created by myself.